# How to get caret/cursor position in RichTextBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I want to get the Caret position in RichTextBox in WPF when I change my cursor with Left Click Mouse Button and this picture below shows this.

[image]

Comment: `TextPointer caretPos = rtb.CaretPosition;`?

Comment: I want to the position change when I use right/left/up/down key Without writing The picture i set illustrates this.

Answer (score 0):

Get position:

```
TextPointer tp = EditMessageRTB.Selection.Start;
```

Set position:

```
RichTextBox.CaretPosition = tp;
```

If want to set position to end:

```
RichTextBox.CaretPosition = RichTextBox.Document.Blocks.LastBlock.ContentEnd;
```